# Creating log file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell program that checks if the site is responding and retrieves data and put it inside a file using invoke-webrequest function. I want to log the response status (200 or either way) of the request with the current date and time of the request. Below is a working script. The only problem is I don't know how to concatenate my datetime variable and my status variable (separated by a space) in a single line in the log file.

```
    $Logfile = "D:\PROJECTS\mylog.log"
    Function LogWrite
    {
       Param ([string]$logstring)

       Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
    }
    $datetime = get-date

    $x = invoke-webrequest -Uri http://somesite/form/Download?uid=$number"&"sdate=$startdate"&"edate=$enddate -OutFile D:\PROJECTS\Timekeeping\build_src\$Branch-$enddate.dat -PassThru
    if($x.StatusCode -eq 200){
        LogWrite $datetime
        LogWrite $x.StatusCode
    }else{
        LogWrite $datetime
        LogWrite $x.StatusCode
    }
```

The result of my mylog.log is:

```
    08/24/2016 18:43:27 its alive!
    08/24/2016 18:43:27 
    200
```

I want it to be like

```
    08/24/2016 18:43:27 its alive!
    08/24/2016 18:43:27 200
```

I tried

```
    LogWrite $datetime+$x.StatusCode
```

and

```
    LogWrite $datetime+" "+$x.StatusCode
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LogWrite "$datetime $($x.StatusCode)"
```

Using `$( <code> )` within a string will evaluate the contents of the brackets first then convert the result into the string. **Note**:You will need to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

[`Add-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849859.aspx) supports `-NoNewLine`:

> Indicates that this cmdlet does not add a new line/carriage return to the content.

I would follow the [`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) metaphor:

```
Function LogWriteLine
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -NoNewLine -value $logstring
}

...

LogWrite $datetime
LogWrite ' '
LogWriteLine $x.StatusCode
```

This allows you to simply output in loops, for example, without having to first build up a in-memory string.